# How to send ajax call for every single percentage instead of milli second for video

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, video

here is my code with this ajax call is going every millisecond and with this some time ajax call is missing at some percentage how can i fix this issue:

```
var percentage = 0.01;
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    var video = document.querySelector('video'); 
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() { 
        totalTime = this.duration;
    });
    $("#video").bind("timeupdate", function() {
        var currentTime = this.currentTime;
        var totalPlayed = 0;
        var played = video.played;

        for (var i = 0; i < played.length; i++) {
            totalPlayed += played.end(i) - played.start(i);
            var playedInPercentage = Math.floor((currentTime/this.duration) * 100);
        }
        // if((playedInPercentage > perecntageCounter) ) {
        videoWatchAjaxCall(course_id,videoId,totalTime,totalPlayed,playedInPercentage,currentTime);
        percentage = percentage+(0.01) ;
        // }
    });
});
```

I want to send ajax call for every single percentage 
In data base i am storing like this:

```
column name = watch_points
value =  1,2,3,4,6,7,8,99,89,78,56,100   like this 0-100 will store.
```

so when ajax calls send for every millisecond either my browser is crashing or some of my watch points are missing when the video is smaller how can i fix this issue.

Comment: Even sending an AJAX request every second is a *really* bad idea. Why do you need to keep the client/server so closely synchronised? I'd suggest using another mechanism, such as websockets, if this really is needed as your current code is basically DDOSing yourself.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I don't mean every second. i want to send ajax call for every one percentge played. i am tracking the video, for that i want to send ajax call for every 1% played, how can i do that..? i hope you understood requirement if need clarification please le know i can explain with example.  Ex:if vidoe is 5mins or 30mins. for everyvideo 100 ajax calls should go for 1 percentage played..

Comment: What happened to percentageCounter that seems like the right approach.  Basically keep a global var percentageCounter that starts at zero and stores the current integer percentage.  When the function is called compare it to the new integer percentage, if they are different update percentageCounter and send the request.  I have seen this implemented with 10% and 25% increments between request sending but never 1%, that might be way too many requests.

Comment: yes due to many requests some watchpoints are not storing thai is my issue with counter what is best solution for it..?  how everyone like youtube and vimeo will track weather video fully watched or not

Comment: If all you want to do is track how much of the video a user watched a better idea would be to call the server once when any of the following events occur: the video playback stops, the video ends, the page is unloaded.